# Cadastrar um "User" do devise através seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou finalizando um projeto e quero criar um usuário default. Toda a estrutura de cadastro de usuário é realizada pelo devise incorporado no rails_admin.

Através de pesquisa encontrei esse sintaxe abaixo entretanto a mesma não funciona:

```
User.create(:email => 'admin@admin.com', :password => 'senha', :password_confirmation => 'senha')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem que rodar o comando:

```
rake db:seed
```

no console.

Comment: Deu certo @ygorbr?

Comment: Obrigado. Era exatamente o que faltava mesmo.